# Passing NSString parameter in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple question about syntax:

```
NSString* inpword1 = @"eight";

NSString* outword1 = [lookFor theKey:inpword1];   // This line does not compile!!!!  

-(NSString*) lookFor: theKey: (NSString*) key;  // in the Spec (translator.h)

-(NSString*) lookFor: theKey: (NSString*) key;  // in the Body (translator.m)
{  
    NSString* entry = [[NSString alloc] init];  

    entry = [dictionary objectForKey:key];  

    return entry;  
}
```

Everything compiles except for the one line.
If there is an obvious problem with the syntax, I haven't been able to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.  I am able to look up words in the dictionary correctly
but when I use the lookFor as a wrapper, I can't seem to get the syntax right for the call.

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Before pointing out the Syntax errors, i have to make it clear that you shouldn't create you own function to retrieve an object for key. this has already been done for you, simply call `[someDictionary objectForKey:@"YourKey"];`

now to our syntax problems-
I see 3 main problems here:

1. `NSString* entry = [[NSString alloc] init]; //this allocation is useless and will result in a memory leak because later, you assign it with an object from the dictionary:`
2. `[lookFor theKey:inpword1]; //This is just a wrong way to call a function:`
3. `-(NSString*) lookFor: theKey: (NSString*) key //this is just a wrong way to declare a function.`

you probably meant:

```
NSString* inpword1 = @"eight";

NSString* outword1 = [self lookForKeyInDict:dict TheKey:inpword1];

-(NSString*) lookForKeyInDict:(NSDictionary*)dict TheKey:(NSString*) key;

-(NSString*) lookForKeyInDict:(NSDictionary*)dict TheKey:(NSString*) key
{  
    NSString* entry;  

    entry = [dict objectForKey:key];  

    return entry;  
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks!  I just didn't know how to do it.  I will try this and see if it works.  I appreciate all your responses.

Comment: You method works, but I think the actual call wasn't quite right!  It left out the dictionary parameter in the call and misspelled the name of the routine.  I used:      NSString* outword1 = [self lookForKeyInDict:dictionary TheKey:inpword1];   // and that worked!

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I agree with you, but I have only owned an iMac for one week and I've been programming for 40 years.  You make me sound like a complete newbie and I am to Objective-C.  The documentation I've found leaves a lot to be desired and that is a monumental understatment.  It's a case of the King's New Clothes.

Comment: I can now move on to the next phase.  Thanks, you solved my problem and that is exactly what I needed, a hint on how to proceed.  I think I can figure out most anything.  I appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: If I am right, you ought to edit that call in case others find my question useful.  I think this is a very confusing syntax and in my opinion it is not well explained in the available literature online.  I am sure plenty of people would agree with me.

Comment: @BrentMartin your correction is right. Sorry- I typed that response using my iPhone : ). I'm glad it helped. however, Getting objects from dictionaries shouldn't be done like that, it helps a lot looking at example codes. maybe see some examples in the iOS Developer Library - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

Comment: @CocoaFu right, these methods are really useless, but just for helping the OP understand how to declare, implement and call functions correctly in Obj-c it's alright. Getting objects from dictionaries shouldn't be done like that - that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In the statement:

```
NSString* outword1 = [lookFor theKey:inpword1];   // This line does not compile!!!!
```

`lookFor` is an instance of some object.
`theKey` is the message being sent to the object.
The class `lookFor` must have a method `thekey` with a type of `NSString *`

Additionally there seems to be confusion on Objective-C message structure, consider reading the Apple documentation on Objective-C, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but it's still confusing.  I've read the documentation till I am blue in the face and it still wasn't obvious how to solve the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brent Statements like: -(NSString*) lookFor: theKey: (NSString*) key; show an incomplete understanding of the Objective-C syntax. It is very different from languages such as C++, Java and C#, it takes some getting used to. The syntax is actually correct but the usage is completely wrong. My suggestion is to really get a good feel for the usage, how and why.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `[lookFor theKey:inpword1];` means you're calling the method `theKey:` with `inpword1` as an argument on an object named `lookFor`.

The syntax `-(NSString*) lookFor: theKey: (NSString*) key;` declares a method `lookFor:theKey:` which takes an `NSString*` called `key` as an argument and returns an `NSString*`. Unfortunately the use of the colon after `lookFor` means that when you try to call this method, `theKey` will be treated as an argument and you'll get an undeclared error. You should never use a colon in a method name unless it's introducing a parameter, as with `theKey:`.

So, in a nutshell, I'd just keep in mind:

- What follows the opening `[` in Objective-C is the name of the object you're calling.
- Colons in method declarations introduce parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that aspect of Objective-C is totally different from C, C++, C#, Java, Pascal, or any other language I have ever used.

Comment: True, the syntax can cause some real headaches. I think the colon idea was borrowed from Smalltalk.